# Joomla Kunena Forum - Change Sections links into tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, tabs

Basicaly I'd like to set Kunena forum sections links as a tabs like [HERE](http://demo.templatekunena.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&view=misc&task=template&name=lumy) . The original code displaying particular sections on the frontpage looks as follow:

```
<?php
/**
 * Kunena Component
 * @package Kunena.Template.Blue_Eagle
 * @subpackage Category
 *
 * @copyright (C) 2008 - 2013 Kunena Team. All rights reserved.
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 * @link http://www.kunena.org
 **/
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ();

$tabclass = array ("row1", "row2" );
$mmm=0;
foreach ( $this->sections as $section ) :
    $htmlClassBlockTable = !empty ( $section->class_sfx ) ? ' kblocktable' . $this->escape($section->class_sfx) : '';
    $htmlClassTitleCover = !empty ( $section->class_sfx ) ? ' ktitle-cover' . $this->escape($section->class_sfx) : '';
?>
<div class="kblock kcategories-<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>">
    <div class="kheader">

        <h2><span><?php echo $this->GetCategoryLink ( $section, $this->escape($section->name) ); ?></span></h2>
        <?php if (!empty($section->description)) : ?>
        <div class="ktitle-desc km hidden-phone">
            <?php echo KunenaHtmlParser::parseBBCode ( $section->description ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="kcontainer" id="catid_<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>">

    <!-- Here Comes Categories Displayed  As Tab Content-->

<!-- Finish: Category Module Position -->   
</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I changed first part from

```
<div class="kheader">

            <h2><span><?php echo $this->GetCategoryLink ( $section, $this->escape($section->name) ); ?></span></h2>
            <?php if (!empty($section->description)) : ?>
            <div class="ktitle-desc km hidden-phone">
                <?php echo KunenaHtmlParser::parseBBCode ( $section->description ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div
```

to

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <ul id="sections-tab" class="nav nav-pills visible-desktop">
        <li class="active">
          <a id="sect<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>" href="#sect<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>" data-toggle="tab">
          <span class="sectiontab<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>"><?php echo $this->GetCategoryLink ( $section, $this->escape($section->name) ); ?></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

but it still showing Sections as normal. I know that I need to move **foreach ( $this->sections as $section )** between navbar class but... to be honest I stuck here because don't know PHP much.
So any help much apretiate.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. Foreach was the answer. And what I did was:

```
<?php
foreach ( $this->sections as $section ) : $x++;
?>
  <?php if ($x == 1) { echo '<li class="active">'; } else {echo '<li>';} ?>
  <a id="sectab<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>" href="#sect<?php echo intval($section->id) ?>" data-toggle="tab">
    <?php echo $this->escape($section->name); ?>
  </a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

of course before **foreach** I added variable **$x=0** which helped me a lot.